# How to use Gtk with CSS?

Tags: css, gtk, gtk3

I have created a text editor use Gtk and would like to style it with Css. How should i do that. By the way, I am using the Code Blocks IDE. This is the first time using gtk with css, so i don't know where to place the files and such. I have added the gtkcssprovider code but it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone please help me fix this problem? Thank you

This is my file structure:

```
testCode
---bin/
---obj/
---file.c
---file.h
---main.c
---testCode (project file)
---testCode.depend
---testCode.layout
---theme.css
```

Heres my main.c:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *scroll;
  //GdkColor color;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 500);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Notepad");
  vBox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vBox);

  GtkCssProvider* css_provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    if(!gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(css_provider, "theme.css", NULL))
    {
        g_object_unref(css_provider);
        return;
    }
    GdkDisplay* display = gdk_display_get_default();
    GdkScreen* screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen(display);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(screen,
                                          GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(css_provider),
                                              GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

  accelGroup = gtk_accel_group_new();
  gtk_window_add_accel_group(GTK_WINDOW(window), accelGroup);
  createMenuBar();
  createToolBar();
  scroll = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scroll),
                               GTK_POLICY_NEVER,
                               GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
  textView = gtk_text_view_new ();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scroll), textView);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vBox),
                   scroll,
                   TRUE,
                   TRUE,
                   0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vBox), textView, 1, 1, 0);
  callBackFunction();
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

Heres the theme.css:

```
GtkWindow {
background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear,
                                center top, center bottom,
                                color-stop(0.5,green),
                                color-stop(0.5,blue),
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? Also you're ignoring the error from `gtk_css_provider_load_from_path()`; don't do that. Catch the error and print what it is.

Comment: wait a minute, why does it say that 'cannot find #include<gtk/gtk.h>' when i tried building and run?

Comment: Your build tool or IDE is probably not set up to find GTK+. What IDE is this? See if there's a list of pkg-config packages and add `gtk+-3.0`.